# Understanding CUDA kernel execution

Tags: c, cuda

I am learning CUDA and I tried the following kernel code.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuPrintf.cu"
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ void func(float &temp,float* dum)
{
    float a=5;
dum[threadIdx.x]=temp+a;
cuPrintf("%f\n",dum[threadIdx.x]);
return;
}
__global__ void kernel(float* d_in, float* d_out)
{
 int tid=(blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)+threadIdx.x;
 float temp=d_in[tid];
 float dum[9];
 func(temp,dum);
 cuPrintf("dum %f\n",dum[threadIdx.x]);
 atomicAdd(&d_out[tid],dum[tid]);
 //d_out[tid]+=dum[tid];
 cuPrintf("d_out %f\n",d_out[threadIdx.x]);
 }

 int main()
 {
    int i;
    cudaError_t cudastatus;
    float in[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    float* h_in=in;
    float* d_in={0};
    cudastatus=cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in,9*sizeof(float));
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
         fprintf(stderr, "cm0 fail %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    cudastatus=cudaMemcpy(d_in,h_in,9*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
         fprintf(stderr, "cm1 fail %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    float* d_out={0};
    cudastatus=cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out,9*sizeof(float));
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
         fprintf(stderr, "cm2 fail %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    cudaMemset(d_out, 0, 9*sizeof(float));
    float out[9]={0};
    cudaPrintfInit();
    kernel<<<3,3>>>(d_in,d_out);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout,true);
    cudaPrintfEnd();
    cudastatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Kernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    cudastatus=cudaMemcpy(out,d_out,9*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
         fprintf(stderr, "cm3 fail %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n",out[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

While I don't get any error in cuda-memcheck and through the cudaError_t checks, the printf gives output inside the device function and the one in the global function are different. (I have tried both simple addition and atomic add operation).

1. What is the reason for this difference and how to correct this?
2. Also, how do we make sure that the device function is called for each value of temp?

Please help me sort this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your device code makes no sense at all. `tid` and `threadIdx.x` cannot be used interchangeably. At the moment your question amounts to "if I set a and then print out b, why don't the values match?", which is just nonsensical.  I have voted to close this.

Comment: Sorry about that typo. My main question is how do I make it call for every value of temp. Should I put a for loop for the function call. How will it happen in parallel then? Sorry I am a newbie. Please don't mind if the question is too silly

Comment: There are basic cuda classes you can take on-line,  which will spell out basic concepts like this for you.  [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-education-training) is a starting point.  [here](http://on-demand-gtc.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php?searchByKeyword=2131&searchItems=session_id&sessionTopic=&sessionEvent=&sessionYear=&sessionFormat=&submit=&select=+) is a link to a good introductory class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are launching three blocks, each with three threads.  In each block, those 3 threads will have the following values, one per thread:

thread 0:  threadIdx.x = 0;
thread 1:  threadIdx.x = 1;
thread 2:  threadIdx.x = 2;

So when you call `func` in each of the the 3 blocks, the threads in all 3 blocks are writing to the same 3 locations of `dum`:

```
dum[threadIdx.x]=temp+a;
```

i.e. only locations 0-2 of this 9 location array are going to be populated by this line of code.

Furthermore, each threadblocks' group of three threads will be writing *different* values to those 3 locations, due to this initialization, which does not use `threadIdx.x` but instead `tid`:

```
float temp=d_in[tid];
```

Since each threadblock is writing different values in `func`, the value printed out in `func` or in the kernel could change *at any time* based on the exact order of threadblock execution. There's no way to make any sense of this.

In short, your mixing of `tid`, a globally unique thread index, and `threadIdx.x`, a threadblock unique thread index, is *quite* confusing, and will lead to unpredictable behavior due to race conditions, because the order of threadblock execution is not specified.

Instead, if you use `tid` throughout, I think you'll get understandable behavior:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuPrintf.cu"
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ void func(float &temp,float* dum, int id)
{
    float a=5;
dum[id]=temp+a;
cuPrintf("%f\n",dum[id]);
return;
}
__global__ void kernel(float* d_in, float* d_out)
{
 int tid=(blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)+threadIdx.x;
 float temp=d_in[tid];
 float dum[9];
 func(temp,dum,tid);
 cuPrintf("dum %f\n",dum[tid]);
 atomicAdd(&d_out[tid],dum[tid]);
 //d_out[tid]+=dum[tid];
 cuPrintf("d_out %f\n",d_out[tid]);
 }

 int main()
 {
    int i;
    cudaError_t cudastatus;
    float in[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    float* h_in=in;
    float* d_in={0};
    cudastatus=cudaMalloc((void**)&d_in,9*sizeof(float));
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
         fprintf(stderr, "cm0 fail %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    cudastatus=cudaMemcpy(d_in,h_in,9*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
         fprintf(stderr, "cm1 fail %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    float* d_out={0};
    cudastatus=cudaMalloc((void**)&d_out,9*sizeof(float));
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
         fprintf(stderr, "cm2 fail %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    cudaMemset(d_out, 0, 9*sizeof(float));
    float out[9]={0};
    cudaPrintfInit();
    kernel<<<3,3>>>(d_in,d_out);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout,true);
    cudaPrintfEnd();
    cudastatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Kernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    cudastatus=cudaMemcpy(out,d_out,9*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudastatus != cudaSuccess) {
         fprintf(stderr, "cm3 fail %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudastatus));
    }
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n",out[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Could you please clarify this. How to ensure that func is called for every value of temp? If I call it in a loop from global function, then how will it compute in parallel? Please help me.

Comment: The code I provided will ensure that `func` is called for every value of `temp`.  When you call it from the global function, each thread (in each block, so 9 threads total) will call that function.  That means all 9 threads will execute `func`, and if you pass a globally-unique thread ID to `func`, then each thread will operate on a different value of `temp`.  SO Q+A format is not ideal for giving a tutorial on CUDA.  Please avail yourself of the resources available.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Thanks a lot for the support. You made my day!